# Geoserver - how clear memory after tile-seeding and normal wmts queries

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, memory

I am currently doing a lot of seeding of tiles in GeoServer and I noticed that after the tiling process is over the memory that is required during the task is not cleared. The same thing happens after a WMTS query, the memory usage goes up but isn't cleared after the request has been fulfilled. The memory is only cleared after I restart GeoServer.

I am running it in Tomcat7 and I am using the following JAVA memory options:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

I have memory BlobStores turned off as well as "Use memory mapped buffers" and "Cache and reuse memory maps" in the Data Stores. I did notice that when you edit a layer and go to "Tile caching" there is an option to "Enable In Memory Caching for this Layer", which is selected and I can't turn it off as it's greyed out. Does anyone know what the solution to this problem is?

Comment: Java managers the memory automatically http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf. Do you have some specific problems with the memory?

Comment: If there is no out of memory issue, don't worry

Comment: Ok good to know, I'm not running out of memory, so I guess everything is fine!

Comment: Actually I'm interested in an answer to this, I would like a way to flush GeoServer's memory use after certain operations in order to free it up for other processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out not be an issue as stated in one of the comments.